# How do I connect to my Outlook/Hotmail calendar and display it in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, calendar, outlook, google-calendar-api

We have been playing with the [Google Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/)
 and are thinking of integrating it into our newest project due to high demand.

However a few of our clients have asked us whether it would be possible to link their hotmail/outlook calendar as well however I am unable to find a sample project that I can run in Visual Studio that displays the Outlook/hotmail calendar and relevant events like the Google calendar does.

The way the GoogleCalendarSample projects works is it's a C# application that when ran in Visual Studio it asks you for your Google login after which it displays your calendar and you can create and edit and delete events. I am after the same thing but for Outlook/Hotmail.

Could anyone point me in the right direction so I achieve the above? Is that even possible?

I have found a few threads but none of them do what we need - I am not after a few lines of code that show how to connect to Outlook - there is plenty of material on that - I am after a sample projects that I can run from VS (has to be C#) that when ran it asks you for the Outlook/Hotmail login and displays the calendar and events etc

Would appreciate pointers in the right direction and useful tips

Comment: Is there something similar but with Office 365 rather than Outlook specifically?

Answer (score 1):

Well outlook.com ( ex hotmail ) has an API or Live Connect API that allows you to access the calendar events too

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh826523.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh826535.aspx

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply - is it me being blind or is there really no link to download a sample working project?

Comment: Yes I do not see any actual project , only sample code . I will add a comment here if I find any working c# project

Comment: I will keep digging as well and will post if I find anything - thank you for your help really appreciate it

Comment: Is there something similar but with Office 365 rather than Outlook specifically?